# How to Restrict Certain Words in Text Using Python

Tags: python

I'm making a program that would reject anything if the word "pass" is being used; be it in uppercase or lowercase letters.

That is if the word pAss or PASS is being used.

It also can't be used in inclusion with other words such as `addass` or `fhsaPasS`.

For example, my input is asdapaSS, and then it is rejected.

The condition is "Does not contain the string “pass” in any combination of upper or lower case characters."

The code below is what I have come up with as of now.

```
input1 = input("Please write a word: ")
lowercase = input1.lower()

if len(lowercase) == "pass":
    print("False")
else:
    print("True")
```

Comment: `len(lowercase)` gets the length of the string. It will never be equal to `"pass"`. What you want is `if "pass" in lowercase`.

Comment: it's not clear what's your question, add some example input and output

Comment: What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. Are you asking how to debug this snippet? Please provide a [mre] with example input, expected output, and actual output. See [ask] if you want general advice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ***in*** [operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

```
if "pass" in input1.lower(): 
    print("false")
```

Comment: `lowercase` is *already* in lowercase. You are doing it twice.

Comment: @MarsNebulaSoup - No they aren't. They are completely negating the arbitrary and unnecessary `lowercase` variable. This is the best answer.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry The question was already edited before your comment. I agree, `lowercase` is unnecessary, but the answer said: `if "pass" in lowercase.lower()`, in which the `.lower()` is redundant, since `lowercase` *is already in lowercase.*

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
while True:
  string = input()

  if "pass" not in  re.findall("pass",string.lower()):
    print("True")
    break
  else:
    print("False")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

This code uses the regular expressions library to check that there is no "pass" in the lowercase version of the string that has just been inputted. findall is used from the regular expressions library to solve it.

```
import re
string = input()

if "pass" not in  re.findall("pass",string.lower()):
    print("True")
    break
else:
    print("False")
```